# Java - If I add a method to a Class, will each instance of it take up more space? Does making the method(s) static change anything?

Tags: java, memory, static

Also, does the size of the method affect how much more space each object would take up (if the answer to the title question is yes)? Or would it be more like a reference to the method, each reference being the same size? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Methods don't add memory space to instance variables, only to the class itself (which is of course also an Object :-)).

Answer (score 2):

Methods and static members of the class are simply represented once in the VM as part of the class definition. The size of each individual instance should only be affected by the non-static member variables in the class.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, a method does not influence the size of the object. It will increase the file size, but not the object size.

Answer (score 1):

Each object has a reference to its class. The number of methods in that class don't matter.

The number of non-static fields make a difference to each object as every object need to have that field. (Unless the JVM optmises away the field)